# UILabel - how to change text position

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add subviews to my UITableView cells.

It works just perfect for me, but the text appears at the very left edge of a cell. How can I move it a little bit to the right side? I want to have a little margin from the left cell border.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
CGRect frame = theLabel.frame;
frame.origin.x += LEFT_MARGIN;
theLabel.frame = frame;
```